# matplotlib event.xdata out of timeries range

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

Having an issue using `matplotlib` `event.xdata` when plotting `pandas.Timeseries`, I tried to reproduce the answer proposed in a [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726450/736151), but get a very strange behavior.

Here's the code, adapted to `python3` and with a little more stuff in the `on_click()` function:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        # provide raw and converted x data
        print(f"{event.xdata} --> {mdates.num2date(event.xdata)}")
    # add a vertical line at clicked location
    line = ax.axvline(x=event.xdata)
    plt.draw()

t = pd.date_range('2015-11-01', '2016-01-06', freq='H')
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, t.size).cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':y}, index=t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line = None
df.plot(ax=ax)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()
```

If I launch this, I get the following diagram, with expected date range between Nov. 2015 and Jan. 2016, as is the cursor position information provided in the footer of the window (here 2015-11-01 10:00), and correct location of the vertical lines:

[image: GUI result of matplotlib code]

However, the command-line output is as follows:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\code\>python matplotlib_even.xdate_num2date.py
402189.6454115977 --> 1102-02-27 15:29:23.562039+00:00
402907.10400704964 --> 1104-02-15 02:29:46.209088+00:00
```

Those `event.xdata` values are clearly out of both input data range and x axis data range, and are unusable for later use (like, try to find the closest y value in the serie).

**So, does anyone know how I can get a correct `xdata`?**

Comment: Close topic to [question about mixing `matplotlib` and `pandas` plotting functions and resulting x-axis ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354195/pandas-vs-matplotlib-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must have changed in the way matplotlib/pandas handles datetime info between [the answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725701/how-to-get-data-in-datetime-format-from-plot-with-events-in-python/34726450#34726450) you linked and now. I cannot comment on why, but I found a solution to your problem.

I went digging through the code that shows the coordinates in the bottom left of the status bar, and I found that when you're plotting a timeseries, pandas patches the functions that prints this info and [replaces it with this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6249355b853878ff06ad8d2affe00d3b629a36ea/pandas/plotting/_timeseries.py#L305).

From there, you can see that you need to convert the float value to a `Period` object.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def on_click(event):
    print(pd.Period(ordinal=int(event.xdata), freq='H'))


t = pd.date_range('2015-11-01', '2016-01-06', freq='H')
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, t.size).cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': y}, index=t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the search, that explains the unexpected behavior of the example. Gimme some time to try out with my real data, which is not based on a `date_range` and for which I'm not sure I can retrieve the `freq` parameter for `pd.Period` call.

Comment: Note that this works well in this case, but in case of e.g. `df.plot(ax=ax, x_compat=True)`, the original attempted solution would need to be used instead. In order to have the original message printed independent of the kind of plot one can also do `print(f"{event.xdata} --> {event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata,event.ydata)}")`.

Comment: Nice one as well, as `format_coord` is indeed [replaced by `pandas`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6249355b853878ff06ad8d2affe00d3b629a36ea/pandas/plotting/_timeseries.py#L343). However, this groups x and y axis together in a `str` object when I'm only interested in the x value in 'native' type.

Comment: OK, after some search, my real issue is quite different (dataframe plot on some sort of timeindex with no `freq`); therefore this answer is relevent, and I'll open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment on this question as one of the notes, namely, print(f"{event.xdata} --> {event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata,event.ydata)}")
is an answer to how to deal with cursors when xaxis is datetime. I have googled this for days in many ways without success. What appears to be the best answer is not; but this is. I attach a simple code example that makes the point. Code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def split_f_c(w):
    xval=w.split(" ")[0]
    val=xval.split("=")[1]
    return val
def on_click(event):
    print("wrong answer with plt.plot:\n",\
          pd.Period(ordinal=int(event.xdata), freq='H'))
    print(f"{event.xdata} --> {event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata,event.ydata)}")
    w=event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata,event.ydata)
    print("xvalue:",split_f_c(w))
    lo=ax.get_xlim()[0]
    hi=ax.get_xlim()[1]
    w=event.inaxes.format_coord(lo,hi)
    lowest=split_f_c(w)
    w=event.inaxes.format_coord(hi,lo)
    highest=split_f_c(w)
    print("in range ",lowest, highest)
t = pd.date_range('2015-11-01', '2016-01-06', freq='H')
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, t.size).cumsum()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': y}, index=t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#df.plot(ax=ax)
plt.plot(t,y)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()
```